# Source code preview unavailable in Coveralls

Tags: java, code-coverage, travis-ci, coveralls

I’m using Travis-CI with Coveralls. Here is my `.travis.yml`

```
language: java
install: mvn install -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.6 -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.6 -DskipTests=true
script: mvn test -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.6 -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.6

after_success:
  - mvn clean cobertura:cobertura coveralls:cobertura
```

The problem is that the source is unavailable (e.g. https://coveralls.io/files/243843344) for my branch https://coveralls.io/r/Krasnyanskiy/jrs-rest-java-client?branch=develop.

Any ideas how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

src/main/java/

in sub directory (in coveralls page indicating the source was not found)